# How to calculate two values from bracket in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating geofencing featured website. So I need to calculate some expression. I have two values related to latitude and longitude.

for e.g:  `var value = '(41.878113,-87.629798)'`

How to separate above two values in javascript

Comment: Is that even valid JavaScript?

Comment: it is not valid but I've used  "var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(42.878113,-87.629798);" And displaying it by alert. So its showing output "(42.878113,-87.629798)"

Comment: I just want to separate that two values from brackets

Comment: Is `(41.878113,-87.629798)` supposed to be a string `"(41.878113,-87.629798)"`? And if it is, I assume that you want the 2 values (strings) in an Array? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

<s>That's not valid JavaScript.</s>  (Post was edited, it wasn't valid at first)

One method you could do is define it as an array:

```
var cords = [41.878113, -87.629798];
```

From here you could reference it like so:

```
cords[0]; // Out: 41.878113
cords[1]; // Out: -87.629798
```

Comment: var value = "(41.878113,-87.629798)". Is the script

Comment: That's perfectly valid javascript

Comment: @naomik, He edited the question, it wasn't a string before.  See the edit history in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps [LatLng API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) provides `.lat()` and `.lng()` functions for accessing them individually.  You can use them like this:

```
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(42.878113,-87.629798);
console.log(coords.lat()); // 42.878113
console.log(coords.lng()); // -87.629798
```

Comment: how to implement that API

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to separate the string at the `,` then remove non-numeric characters

```
var value = '(41.878113,-87.629798)';

var parts = value.split(',');
//=> ["(41.878113", "-87.629798)"]

var lat = parts[0].replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
//=> "41.878113"

var lng = parts[1].replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
//=> "-87.629798"
```

---

Now you can use them in some sort of calculation

```
calculateSomething(lat, lng);
```

Which would be the same as

```
calculateSomething("41.878113", "-87.629798");
```

Comment: This is working with:                                                                                "  var j = '(63572,3486254)';
   var parts = j.split(',');
   var lat = parts[0].replace(/[^\d.-]/g,'');"                                                       But this is not working with : "var myLatlng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114,-87.629798);
   var lng = parts[1].replace(/[^\d.-]/g,'');  var parts = myLatlng4.split(',');
   var lat = parts[0].replace(/[^\d.-]/g,'');"

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is a String that is always in that format and you want an Array that contains the 2 values in String format , this example should suffice

```js
var value = '(41.878113,-87.629798)';


document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(value.slice(1, -1).split(','), null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```